# Azure Blob storage lifecycle management

Tags: azure, lifecycle, azure-blob-storage

I am currently using Azure Blobs to store data for a project. I want Azure to automatically delete old entries (data points) which are older then X number of days. I have found the following documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts?tabs=azure-portal

It essentially says that this can be done using lifecycle management and defining a new rule. 
However, this documentation is over 6 months old and I cannot seem to find an option to select lifecycle management and define a new rule.

Has anyone else encountered this problem or know where I can access lifecycle management for an Azure Blob as of 2020?

Comment: What kind of storage account for which you're trying to accomplish this?

Comment: Account kind: BlobStorage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a feature available today, I just confirmed on a storage account. You need to make sure you are using a V2 storage account, it will not be present on a v1, or blob only storage account.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue, where the option for Life cycle management wasn't available but it was available on other storage accounts.
Check the performance/access tier. If it's set to Premium then its Life cycle management isn't available. Try creating a storage account with Standard.
If your using an arm template try Standard_RAGRS for the sku parameter.

screenshot of storage account in portal:
[image]